# jQuery scrolling menu not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have a link like so `<a href='#overview'>Overview</a>` and a html section like so `<section id="overview" class="community"></section>`

and I have this jquery code that is suppose to scroll to that section from where I clicked the link and the #overview is not suppose to in the url or address bar.

```
$(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                        var target = $(this.hash);
                        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                        if (target.length) {
                                $('html,body').animate({
                                        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 115
                                }, 2000);
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        });
    });
```

my problem is, it doesn't...it will scroll to that section from the bottom of the page to the top of the section and #overview is appearing in the url what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this ? What I am expecting to happen is when I click on the link, scroll from the link (which is at the top of the page) to the top of the section.

Could the issue be that my url looks like so: `site.php?string=aaaa`

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you could clean up your html and deal only with classes, put and `.internal-click` on every link where you want this functionality and a class, like overview, that corresponds to the `id` (overview) where it goes. This way you won't repeat code.

```
<a href='#' class="overview internal-click">Overview</a>

$('.internal-click').click(function() {
    var place_to_go = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[0];
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#'+place_to_go).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drpr3bvp/

Comment: this did not work, could the issue be my url? it looks like this `site.php?string=aaaa`

Comment: @user979331 I don't know why you involve the url in the whole thing. with jquery click events the url is not modified. did you remove #overview from your html? it should be just <a href='#' or <a href='javasccript:void(0)'